# Rxjs operator similar to combineLatest but that trigger if only one emit

Tags: typescript, rxjs

In the RxJs doc of `combineLatest`, there is written:

> Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each
> observable emits at least one value.

Is there an operator that works like `combineLatest` but that emit a value even if only one of the observable emits a value ?

Comment: I think you're looking for withLatestFrom.

Comment: You maybe look for `merge`. But it only emits the emitted value, not the values from the other observables. Another approach: You could pipe each observable of `combineLatest` to emit an initial value with `startWith`.

Comment: @Mrk Sef answer looks almost legit to me, but with the cost of introducing potential `null` values. What is the underlying reason you asked the question? It feels to me that potentially it could be addressed in a bit more elegant way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `observables` is an array of observables

```
combineLatest(...observables.map(
  s => s.pipe(
    startWith(null)
  )
)).pipe(
  filter(arr => arr.filter(x => x != null).length > 0)
)
```

This will emit an array with null in any position where the source observable hasn't emitted yet. It also filters out the very first emission where the entire array is null.

---

#### Update based on comment:

The same thing, but perhaps a bit more robust as it allows for a dummy value with a shape that the developer knows.

You can replace 'null' with anything. For example:

```
combineLatest(...observables.map(
  s => s.pipe(
    startWith({dummy: true})
  )
)).pipe(
  filter(arr => arr.filter(x => !x?.dummy).length > 0)
)
```

---

#### Update to improve performance:

At scale, looping through an array to see if all values are void/dummy values is bad for performance. Since (in this case) we only want to ignore the first emission, this custom operator can do that without checking the values at all.

`filterFirst(n)` will ignore the first `n` emmissions:

```
function filterFirst<T>(n: number): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>{
  return s => defer(() => {
    let count = 0;
    return s.pipe(
      filter(_ => n <= count++)
    )
  });
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
combineLatest(...observables.map(
  s => s.pipe(
    startWith(null)
  )
)).pipe(
  filterFirst(1)
)
```

Comment: The only (small) problem may be if `[null, ..., null]` is a proper value. Safer would be to use a unique symbol / reference in a general case.

Comment: Obviously ! Exactly what I was looking for <3

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I made a second update that I think meets the general case and should also be much quicker.