# I need something like combineLatest but when any observable emits

Tags: angular, rxjs

So my code is:

```
combineLatest([obs1, obs2]).subscribe((x => {
  console.log(x)
})
```

The log statement should be fired when EITHER observable emits. However, there is a gotcha as described in the [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest):

> combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value

I need it to emit even if one of the original observables has never emitted. How would I do this?

Comment: mmm thinking about this maybe u just subscribe to the multiple observables individually

Comment: Do you only want to log? Or do you need the value of both observables in the sibscription?

Comment: What do you need this for ? If you want to trigger some logic each time one of these observables emit something, you can use [`merge()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge).

Comment: Pretty sure this was answered a few days ago. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039188/rxjs-operator-similar-to-combinelatest-but-that-trigger-if-only-one-emit

Comment: How about merge operator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rxjs operator similar to combineLatest but that trigger if only one emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039188/rxjs-operator-similar-to-combinelatest-but-that-trigger-if-only-one-emit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

typical use startWith with each observable

```
combineLatest([
   obs1.pipe(startWith(null)),
   obs2.pipe(startWith(null)]
   ).subscribe((x => {
      console.log(x)
   })
```

Comment: you might want to add skip(1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Merge](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/merge) method.

```
merge(obs1, obs2).subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example of how it might be implemented (rather than adding `pipe(startWith(null))` to each Observable in the list).

```js
// overloading:

function combineLatestAny<O1 extends ObservableInput<any>>(sources: [O1]): Observable<[ObservedValueOf<O1>]>;
function combineLatestAny<O1 extends ObservableInput<any>, O2 extends ObservableInput<any>>(sources: [O1, O2]): Observable<[ObservedValueOf<O1>, ObservedValueOf<O2>]>;
function combineLatestAny<O1 extends ObservableInput<any>, O2 extends ObservableInput<any>, O3 extends ObservableInput<any>>(sources: [O1, O2, O3]): Observable<[ObservedValueOf<O1>, ObservedValueOf<O2>, ObservedValueOf<O3>]>;
function combineLatestAny<O1 extends ObservableInput<any>, O2 extends ObservableInput<any>, O3 extends ObservableInput<any>, O4 extends ObservableInput<any>>(sources: [O1, O2, O3, O4]): Observable<[ObservedValueOf<O1>, ObservedValueOf<O2>, ObservedValueOf<O3>, ObservedValueOf<O4>]>;
function combineLatestAny<O1 extends ObservableInput<any>, O2 extends ObservableInput<any>, O3 extends ObservableInput<any>, O4 extends ObservableInput<any>, O5 extends ObservableInput<any>>(sources: [O1, O2, O3, O4, O5]): Observable<[ObservedValueOf<O1>, ObservedValueOf<O2>, ObservedValueOf<O3>, ObservedValueOf<O4>, ObservedValueOf<O5>]>;
function combineLatestAny<O1 extends ObservableInput<any>, O2 extends ObservableInput<any>, O3 extends ObservableInput<any>, O4 extends ObservableInput<any>, O5 extends ObservableInput<any>, O6 extends ObservableInput<any>>(sources: [O1, O2, O3, O4, O5, O6]): Observable<[ObservedValueOf<O1>, ObservedValueOf<O2>, ObservedValueOf<O3>, ObservedValueOf<O4>, ObservedValueOf<O5>, ObservedValueOf<O6>]>;
function combineLatestAny<O extends ObservableInput<any>>(sources: O[]): Observable<ObservedValueOf<O>[]>;

// implementation:

function combineLatestAny(sources) {
  return new Observable<any>(observer => {
    const subscribtion = new Subscription();
    const values = new Array(sources.length);
    let active: number = sources.length;

    sources.forEach((source, index) => subscribtion.add(
      source.subscribe({
        next: value => { values[index] = value; observer.next(values) },
        error: error => { observer.error(error); subscribtion.unsubscribe() },
        // only complete when all input observables have completed
        complete: () => (--active === 0) && observer.complete() 
      })
    ))

    return {
      unsubscribe: () => subscribtion.unsubscribe()
    }
  })
}
```

Usage:

```js
combineLatestAny([timer(1000), timer(3000).pipe(mapTo("string")), timer(2000).pipe(mapTo(true))])
  .subscribe(
    {
      next: console.log,
      error: console.error,
      complete: () => console.log("completed")
    }
  )
```